# Share large constant data among cuda threads

Tags: c++, cuda, opencl

I have a kernel which is called multiple times. In each call a constant data of around 240 kbytes will be shared and processed by threads. Threads work independently like a map function. The stalling time of the threads is considerable. The reason behind that can be the bank conflict of memory reads. How can I handle this?(I have GTX 1080 ti)

Can "const global" of opencl handle this? (because constant memory in cuda is limited to 64 kb)

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that bank conflicts are responsible for what you are seeing. Proposing a countermeasure would require a detailed description of your use case, which you have failed to provide

Comment: You can pack the access indices into a uniformly incrementing array and reorder workitems to fit them so that accesses become coalesced?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In CUDA, I believe the best recommendation would be to make use of the so called "Read-Only" cache.  This has at least two possible benefits over the `__constant__` memory/constant cache system:

1. It is not limited to 64kB like `__constant__` memory is.
2. It does not expect or require "uniform access" like the constant cache does, to deliver full access bandwidth/best performance.  Uniform access refers to the idea that all threads in a warp are accessing the same location or same constant memory value (per read cycle/instruction).

The read-only cache is documented in [the CUDA programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#ldg-function).  Possibly the easiest way to use it is to [decorate your  pointers](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#global-memory-3-0) passed to the CUDA kernel with `__restrict__` (assuming you are [not aliasing between pointers](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#restrict)) and to decorate the pointer that refers to the large constant data with `const ... __restrict__`.  This will allow the compiler to generate appropriate LDG instructions for access to constant data, pulling it through the read-only cache mechanism.

This read-only cache mechanism is only supported on cc 3.5 or higher GPUs, but that covers some GPUs in the Kepler generation and all GPUs in the Maxwell, Pascal (including your GTX 1080 ti), Volta, and Turing generations.

If you have a GPU that is less than cc3.5, possibly the best suggestion for similar benefits (larger than `__const__`, not needing uniform access) then would be to use texture memory.  This is also documented elsewhere in the programming guide, there are various CUDA sample codes that demonstrate the use of texture memory, and plenty of questions here on the SO `cuda` tag covering it as well.

Comment: I get error with nvcc on Windows when using `__restrict__`. Is there any cross-platform way to use this?

Comment: You're doing something wrong then. `__restrict__` is accepted by nvcc both on windows and linux.  Please, let's not try to sort it out here.  If you have a new question, ask a new question.  Both the `nbody` and `p2pBandwidthLatencyTest` cuda sample projects have `__restrict__` decorated kernels.  You may wish to study those projects and compile them on your windows setup.

Comment: "This read-only cache mechanism is only supported on ... **Volta, and Turing generations.**" Could you confirm that this is true for Volta and Turing? From the 3rd chapter in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.07486.pdf), there is no read-only cache in Volta and Turing's memory hierarchy.

Comment: I don't know about that paper, but the NVIDIA documentation I linked in my answer indicates that: 1. the read-only function is supported on GPUs of cc3.5 and higher (with no exclusion for 7.x) and furthermore: 2. the global memory description of 7.x indicates that it is the same as 5.x, and the 5.x global memory description includes specific description of read-only cache.  It's entirely possible that the read-only cache function has been merged with some other functional unit in the GPU in the case of cc7.x, but this does not mean the functionality is not present.

Answer (score 1):

Constant memory that doesn't fit in the hardware's constant buffer will typically "spill" into `global` memory on OpenCL. Bank conflicts are usually an issue with *`local`* memory, however, so that's probably not it. I'm assuming CUDA's 64kiB constant limit reflects nvidia's hardware, so OpenCL isn't going to magically perform better here.

Reading global memory without a predictable pattern can of course be slow, however, especially if you don't have sufficient thread occupancy and arithmetic to mask the memory latency.

Without knowing anything further about your problem space, this also brings me to the directions you could take further optimisations, assuming your global memory reads are the issue:

- Reduce the amount of constant/global data you need, for example by using more efficient types, other compression mechanisms, or computing some of the values on the fly (possibly storing them in `local` memory for all threads in a group to share).
- Cluster the most frequently used data in a small `constant` buffer, and explicitly place the more rarely used constants in a `global` buffer. This may help the runtime lay it out more efficiently in the hardware. If that doesn't help, try to copy the frequently used data into `local` memory, and make your thread groups large and comparatively long-running to hide the copying hit.
- Check if thread occupancy could be improved. It usually can, and this tends to give you substantial performance improvements in almost any situation. (except if your code is already extremely ALU/FPU bound)

Comment: Is there any doc anywhere describing constant memory spilling into global?

Comment: @AntiEarth For example, in [AMD's OpenCL optimisation guide](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_OpenCL_Programming_Optimization_Guide2.pdf), section 3.3: "1. Globally scoped constant arrays. These arrays are initialized, globally
scoped, and in the constant address space (…). If the size of an array is below 64 kB, it is placed in hardware constant buffers; otherwise, it uses global memory. An example of this is a lookup table for math functions." and "2.  Per-pointer attribute specifying the maximum pointer size. This is specified using the max_constant_size(N) attribute.…"

Comment: @AntiEarth I didn't find any explicit documentation for the behaviour on nvidia's implementation, but it seems those GPUs can cache up to 64KiB of constant memory. So I guess it depends on your access patterns there.

Comment: ahh thanks very much! Yea I'm skeptical this happens in CUDA which is a shame